# ayuda graficos Columnas Google Chart

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-api, google-chart-api

Estimado, necesito de sus conocimientos, tengo el siguiente problema, necesito quitar el nombre de cada columna pero si mostrar el Q de cada una de ellas, actualmente tengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver sale el Q en cada columna y tambien sale el nombre de cada supervisor, pero al ser muchos registros esto se visualiza de manera erronea, el codigo lo genero de la siguiente forma

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
      function drawCharts() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Supervisor", "Cantidad", { role: "style" } ],
          <?php
            $sql ="SELECT count(nota) as cantidad, supervisor, fecha_respuesta
                    FROM feedback_nps 
                     where site ='$empresa' and supervisor is not null and month(fecha_respuesta)=month(SYSDATE())-1 group by supervisor  order by cantidad desc;";            
            $stmt=$db->query($sql);    
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
              if ($row['supervisor']==$nombre) {
                echo " ['".$row['supervisor']."',".$row['cantidad'].",'blue' ],";
              }else{
                echo " ['".$row['supervisor']."',".$row['cantidad'].",'color: #e5e4e2' ],";
              }
              
            }
          ?> 
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
                         { calc: "stringify",
                           sourceColumn: 1,
                           type: "string",
                           role: "annotation" },
                         2]);

        var options = {
          title: "Detractores por Supervisor",
          width: 900,
          bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
          
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("top_x_div"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
      };
```

Me podrian ayudar a quitar ese valor?, ahora tengo otro grafico que esta generado de una manera diferente, pero no me sirve porque no logro mostrar el Q de cada columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual tiene el siguiente codigo

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Empresa', 'Cantidad'],
          <?php
            $sql ="SELECT count(nota) as cantidad, site 
                    FROM feedback_nps where supervisor is not null and month(fecha_respuesta)=month(SYSDATE())-1 group by site  order by cantidad desc;";            
            $stmt=$db->query($sql);    
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
              echo " ['".$row['site']."',".$row['cantidad']." ],";
            }
          ?> 
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: {
            title: 'Detractores por Site' },
          hAxis: {
            maxTextLines: 10,
            textStyle: {
              fontSize: 12,
            }
          },          
          bar: { groupWidth: "70%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      };
```

Existe alguna forma de mostrar el Q de cada columna sin tener que mostrar el nombre, espero ser claro en mi duda y como siempre un agradecido de sus conocimientos,

Saludos,

Comment: Que es el `Q`? Puedo hacerme una idea por el contexto pero mejor aclararlo.

Comment: Seria la columna Cantidad, entiendo que hay dos parámetros mas que son  {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'} pero solo quiero mostrar el numero de cada columna, es decir, la cantidad no quiero mostrar el nombre en la parte inferior, es posible